# Python sending file over sockets encoding issue

Tags: python, python-2.7, sockets, unicode, encode

I have an issue when trying to send image files over sockets.

I can send raw text files fine but I can't send image files, the file type im trying to send is specificially a png. In this case the client sends the image to the server, after the server requests it. The error I get is below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Adasli199/Desktop/fileModifyServer.py", line 197, in <module>
    readCommand()
  File "C:/Users/Adasli199/Desktop/fileModifyServer.py", line 81, in readCommand
    result = downloadFile(command[5:])
  File "C:/Users/Adasli199/Desktop/fileModifyServer.py", line 180, in downloadFile
    file.write(data)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\ufffd' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

The code for the server is as follows:

```
import socket

def startServer():
    global serversocket
    global clientsocket
    global address

    serversocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    serversocket.bind((socket.gethostname(), 8010))
    serversocket.listen(5)
    print "Server started"

    clientsocket, address = serversocket.accept()
    print "Client connected"

def downloadFile(command):
    print "download command received"
    print "command is "+command
    i = 0

    for char in command:

        if char == " ":
            src = command[:i]
            dst = command[i+1:]

        i += 1

    print "src is "+src
    print "dst is "+dst
    print "sending request to client"
    clientsocket.send("wget "+src)
    print "awaiting file size data from client"
    fileSize = clientsocket.recv(1024).decode(errors="replace")
    print "size of file to be downloaded is "+str(fileSize)

    if fileSize == "False":
        return False
    else:
        print "opening file"
        file = open(dst, "wb")
        print "awaiting file data from client"
        data = clientsocket.recv(int(fileSize)+4096).decode(errors="replace")
        print "received file data from client"
        print data

        if data == "no permissions":
            return "no permissions"
        else:
            print "writing file data to localhost file"
            file.write(data)
            print "closing file"
            file.close()
            return True

startServer()
downloadFile("filename.png filename.png")
```

And here is the client code:

```
import socket
import os

def startClient():
    global s
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect(("server ip", 8010))

def uploadFile(command):
    print "upload command received from server"

    if os.path.exists(command):
        print "file exists, sending file size to server."
        s.send(str(os.path.getsize(command)))
        print "file size is "+str(os.path.getsize(command))
        file = open(command, "rb")
        data = file.read()
        file.close()
        print data
        try:
            print "sending file data to server"
            s.send(data)
            print "file data sent succesfully, returning true."
            return True
        except:
            return "no permissions"
    else:
        s.send("False")

startClient()

while True:
    command = s.recv(1024).decode(errors="replace")
    print "command received from server. Command is "+command

    if command[:4] == "wget":
        print "wget command received, running uploadFile function."
        uploadFile(command[5:])
```

I have already tried using the socket.sendfile() method and that produces a different error, and I'd like to avoid using if it is not too difficult.

Again I know it is a problem with specifically receiving image files because I can send text files with no problem, which indicates the rest of my code is fine. All of the print statements are in there for debugging purposes only and wont be seen by the user in the final product.

Additional info that might be useful - The server DOES receive the data, as the print statement saying file data received is printed. Additionally both the client and server print a bunch of garbage characters most of which cant be read by ascii and are replaced by a diamond with a question mark. This is not what you'd expect when reading binary, since I open the file in the client in binary read mode, you'd expect 0's and 1's.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: dont `.decode(errors="replace")` the data read from the socket once you start reading the image.

Comment: that fixed it thanks!